# js highcharts, having problems creating the chart series

Tags: javascript, arrays, highcharts

I'm using this as an example

https://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/0k4m5d2q/

I removed the parts were he uses hardcoded data for these lines

Replaced this

```
var originalCategories = [new Category('A'), new Category('B'), new Category('C')].map(function(cat, i) {
    cat.index = i;
    return cat
  });
```

With this

```
array_axis= ['2015', '2016', '2017', '2018', '2019', '2020'];//this comes from my DB
    const originalCategories = array_axis.map(x => (new Category(x))).map((c, i) => {
                c.index = i; 
                return c;
            });
```

and this

```
var originalSeries = [{
    data: [5, 3, 2].map((y, i) => new Point(originalCategories[i], y)) // automatically assign category
  }, {
    data: [1, 7, 4].map((y, i) => new Point(originalCategories[i], y)) // -//-
  }];
```

With this(I think this is the part of the code that doesn't work)

```
array_x =[{name: '15 a 24 años', data: '23.9,25.4,25.4,23.1,21.8,26.8'},
{name: '25 a 34 años', data: '20.8,24.3,20.0,17.5,18.0,20.4'},
{name: '35 a 44 años', data: '22.3,24.6,23.5,21.7,19.6,24.1'},
{name: '45 a 64 años', data: '20.9,21.6,21.3,18.0,18.8,20.6'},
{name: '65 años y más', data: '21.7,22.7,18.9,17.5,18.1,19.4'},
{name: 'Menor de 15 años', data: '36.9,40.1,35.9,34.2,33.1,37.0'}];//this also comes from my DB


    var originalSeries = [];
    $.each(array_x, function(key, value) {
       var unformated_data = value.data;
       var graph_data = unformated_data.split(',').map(parseFloat);
       originalSeries.push(graph_data.map((y, i) => new Point(originalCategories[i], y))) // automatically assign category
                
                
    });
```

but the chart is not showing and I get error msg:
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

not sure what I'm doing wrong. I also need to display the name of each series (those are inside array_x)instead of series 1, series 2,...

I already tested the code with hardcoded data on the originalSeries and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that the `array_x` is an object - not an array, so there using the $.each returns error.

Comment: mm nope, I console.log(graph_data) which is inside the $.each and it returned the arrays=
Array(6)0: 23.91: 25.42: 25.43: 23.14: 21.85: 26.8length: 6[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: Take a look at the code that you have shared - it is not an array. After changing in to the array, you can see that your data structure is different than it was in the initial demo - your code returns array of points, not an array of objects with the data property. To fix it we need to change the `serie.data` into the `serie` (line 48 in the original demo). Proposal of the solution: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/p3vhk69w/

Comment: not working for some reason, even when I just copy the const array_x from your fiddle and running a few test

Comment: @ChrisG could you reproduce your attempt? In the demo that I shared everything work as expected.

Comment: I edited my answer to show the error msg I get and a console.log() of originalSeries after the $.each(). I'm using this picture because in the demo that you shared, I get no errors there either.

Comment: @ChrisG I am not able to say something more from the picture. Please reproduce your code on some online editor.

Comment: Already solved the issue, sorry I guess I needed to show the rest of my code so that it would be easy for you to tell what the problem was and it was a dumb mistake, it has nothing to do with the answer you initially gave me but thank you for your time and help. It wasn't a "straight to the error" solution but it did helped me realize a few things in my code and got me on my way to solving it, so marking your answer as correct.

Comment: I just have 1 more question tho. How do I change the series name?

Comment: @ChrisG glad that you have found a satisfying solution to your case. To change a series name you need to define the `series.name` config. https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.name in your case the series is created dynamically you can try this approach (line 85): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zo3snLmf/

Comment: ty, that helped a lot, finally finished this graph while learning a bunch of stuff while at it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sharing my fiddle of how the code looks now for everyone else to see, if they are interested in solving a similar issue or are planning to create something similar to this.

This is the end result of what I needed to acomplish. I hope someone finds this useful. Thanks to Sebastian Wędzel for the help.

Here is where I push values inside the seriesName array

```
var originalSeries = [];
var seriesName = [];
$.each(array_x, function(key, value) {
    var graph_data = value.data.split(',').map(parseFloat);
    seriesName.push(value.name);//This I will use for my series name
    originalSeries.push(graph_data.map((y, i) => new Point(originalCategories[i], y))) // automatically assign category
});
```

And here is where I set the names for my series using that array

```
function filterSeries() {
    var filteredSeries = [];
    $.each(originalSeries, function(i, serie) {
      // serie options are merged during update, 
      // so it's enough to initialize serie object only with data property
      var newSerie = {
        data: []
      };
      //newSerie.name = serie[i].y.name;
      newSerie.name = seriesName[i];
      $.each(serie, function(i, point) {
        if (point.category.visible) {
            newSerie.data.push(point);
        }
      });
      filteredSeries.push(newSerie);
    });
    return filteredSeries;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/on2z6tmr/19/